# Redirect bare domain to www subdomain for AWS S3 website w/ CloudFront & SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

1. I've got an S3 bucket (`www.getscala.com`) configured as a web site.
2. AWS Certificate Manager made a wildcard certificate for `*.getscala.com`
3. I made a CloudFront distribution with 2 CNAMEs: `www.getscala.com` and `getscala.com`
4. I associated the certificate with the CloudFront distribution
5. Made an A record alias in Route 53 for `www.getscala.com.` that points to the CloudFront distribution

A browser visiting https://www.getscala.com sees the desired web site, served via SSL.

Now the problem: I want to redirect requests for the naked domain, regardless of protocol, to `https://www.getscala.com`.

I created a bucket called `getscala.com` and forwarded to `www.getscala.com` or `https://www.getscala.com`.

Seems that a URL rewrite is not easy with AWS, or at least setting up URL rewrite is not obvious. What am I missing?

Comment: The www-to-bare logic is reversed, but the answer (and question) is the same -- you need a second CloudFront distribution pointed to the bucket doing the redirect.  Both distributions can share the same ACM certficate, or you can use two certs, but this is the only solution to make https work with a redirect, using native AWS capabilities.

Comment: Why create 2 Cloud Front distribution and increase the cost if that can be achieved by only one Cloud Front Distribution. Below answer is more good than your costly solution.

Comment: Yes, this is a better answer, and the questions are similar but not just reversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request the SSL certificate you can add another domain to that certificate. So add getscala.com domain to that certificate. Then set the C-Name above for cloud front. Check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Oh, yes, I will try that!

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! (but I had to create another certificate)

Comment: Yes you cannot edit already created certificate.

Comment: Hmm, everything works except https://getscala.com/ does not resolve ... the browser just spins and waits forever

Comment: When I type getscala.com in my browser it redirects but when I type https:// getscala.com it does not

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to type but the system does not display the preceding https unless you put a space as you did. Any ideas on how to get https:// getscala.com to resolve?

Comment: example.com → www.example.com redirection capability of S3 is http only what is this http://imgur.com/a/wPkHP setting for your cloud front?